# SQL query doesn't retrieve correct result with count

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I have these tables

- `Actor`: id | name
- `Acting`: actor_id| movie|id
- `Movie`: id | title

I have the code which returns how many the number of movies that an actor has acted in

```
SELECT a.name AS name, COUNT(ag.actor_id)
FROM actor a 
LEFT JOIN acting ag ON a.id = ag.actor_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

```
           name           | count
--------------------------+-------
 Bianca Brigitte VanDamme |     1
 Karin Konoval            |     1
 Keri Maletto             |     1
 Terence Bernie Hines     |     1
 Jean Stapleton           |     1
 Kyle Hebert              |     1
 Brandon Middleton        |     1
 Timothy Webber           |     1
 Dana Hanna               |     1
 Travis Betz              |     1
```

After inserting a random actor to the actors table, I run the same code but the output does not have the new actor.

```
INSERT INTO Actor 
VALUES (5000, 'Jeremy Bearimy') 

-- Run same code
SELECT a.name ........
FROM ...
```

I get this result:

```
           name           | count
--------------------------+-------
 Bianca Brigitte VanDamme |     1
 Karin Konoval            |     1
 Keri Maletto             |     1
 Terence Bernie Hines     |     1
 Jean Stapleton           |     1
 Kyle Hebert              |     1
 Brandon Middleton        |     1
 Timothy Webber           |     1
 Dana Hanna               |     1
 Travis Betz              |     1
```

When I run the query with the code to see which actor has acted in 0 movies, I get a result, so I don't know why they don't appear in the query result.

```
SELECT a.name AS name, COUNT(ag.actor_id)
FROM actor a 
LEFT JOIN acting ag ON a.id = ag.actor_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
HAVING COUNT(ag.actor_id) = 0 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

Output:

```
      name      | count
----------------+-------
 Jeremy Bearimy |     0
```

Comment: Did you commit after insert?

Comment: Try removing the LIMIT 10

Comment: @ekochergin I don't know what commiting after insert is, but I don't know if that does anything as I can get the new tuple from the last query, so it is definitely in the table

Comment: @NickW How would removing the limit operator help? The output is already in ascending order and if it the tuple is not the first result in the output then its wrong right.

Comment: It would help if you provide `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements so we can reproduce the result. Otherwise, I won't believe it.

Comment: There must be something you are not telling us. You query [works as you expect it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0388ca64b9cf7db140125a57016bfd8f)

Comment: You're correct, sorry for the inconvenience!! I looked at the code you provided and saw that I ordered by count(*), while you ordered by count(ag.actor_id), which made my query appear much later in the result. [edited](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5daf4f4dd8ff6057b7fe8e6c6432e6c7)

Answer (score 1):

Note your `order by` clause in the first query:

```
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC
```

Actors that are in 1 movie will have a `COUNT(*)` of `1`.  I think that is obvious.

Actors that are in 0 movies will also have a `COUNT(*)` of `1`.  Why?  Because there is one row in the group *even if the columns from the second table are `NULL`*.

You are then limiting to 10 results.  There is no second `ORDER BY` key, so the 10 returned rows are an arbitrary mix, starting with the actors that are in 0 or 1 movies.

If you instead used:

```
ORDER BY COUNT(ag.actor_id) ASC
```

then the actors with zero movies would appear before those with 1 movie.

Answer (score 0):

from the last output it looks like actor 'Jeremy Bearimy' is missing in the acting table

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns the 10 first actor, and they all have 1 movie. You have at least 10 actors with 1 movie. The ones that don't have movies can't appear in the result.

Remove the limit 10 and you will see all the actors with a movie or not.

Comment: "*The ones that don't have movies can't appear in the result.*" - yes they can because of the outer join. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0388ca64b9cf7db140125a57016bfd8f

Comment: No they can't because of the Limit 10. When The limit is reached, it's reached. Postgresql will not give you more than 10 rows in the result and it will be the same with SQL Server or another database. If you ask for 10 rows you get 10 rows and no more respecting the order you ask fo.

Comment: But those with zero movies should be included in the first 10 as the (should) have a count of zero so those rows would be in the first 10

Comment: If you remove the limit what is the result ?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0388ca64b9cf7db140125a57016bfd8f